# How to convert integer to 8-digit binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, cryptography, hamming-distance

I am working on this challenge: [Challenge #6](http://cryptopals.com/sets/1/challenges/6)

I had a working binary and Hamming distance functions, but the binary function just stopped working. It is giving me a

```
"ValueError: Unknown format code 'b' for object of type 'str'"
```

error code for some reason. This is the code that I used for both...

```
# returns only 1's and 0's of binary for int n
def binary(n):
    return '{0:08b}'.format(n)

# returns hamming distance of s1 and s2
def Hamm(s1, s2):
    d = 0   # number of differences between s1 and s2 binary
    for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2):  # compares s1[x] and s2[x]
        if c1 != c2:
            for a, b in zip(binary(c1), binary(c2)):
                if a != b:
                    d += 1  # if 1 or 0 do not match up, d = d + 1
    print(d)
```

Comment: `n` can be string, not int - ie. `'{0:08b}'.format("1")` and you get error.

Answer (score 1):

`n` can be string, not int - ie.

```
'{0:08b}'.format("1")
```

and you get error.

So you need `int()`

```
'{0:08b}'.format( int(n) )
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. This helped. I found the issue. I was passing in 't' instead of ord('t').

Comment: my new issue is that when I try "Hamm(h1, h2) / size", it gives the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Is it saying that Hamm(h1, h2) return NoneType? If so, why is it not an integer?

Comment: because you didn't use `return` to return value - `print()` is not used to return value from function but only to send text on screen. Every function as default uses `return None`

Comment: Ohhh ok... I just forgot to change that back. My mistake. Thank you, again.